# Without using the Residue Theorem, evaluate the integral

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

> Evaluate
>
> $$\int _C\frac{ e^{iz}\, dz}{(z+2i)^7}$$
>
> where C is given by the square with vertices $(\pm3,\ 3)$, $(\pm3, -3)$

I know that there is one singularity at $z=-2i$, which lies inside the contour $C$.

So, by Cauchy's Integral Theorem, we have:
$$\int _C\frac{ e^{iz}\, dz}{(z+2i)^7}$$
$$=\int _C\frac{e^{iz\,}dz}{(z+2i)^{(6+1)}}$$
$$=\frac{2\pi i}{6!} f^{(6)}(-2i)$$ where $f(z)=e^{iz}$

Evaluating the above at $z=-2$, we obtain:
$$\frac{2\pi i}{720} (-e^{-2i^2})$$
$$=\frac{\pi i}{360}(-e^2)$$

Is this right? I'm not sure if $f(z)$ does in fact equal $e^{iz}$ in this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It looks just fine to me!

Comment: Awesome, thanks!!